# setTag: in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, tags

How do you call `setTag:` for `id` type objects?

Comment: Huh?  You'll have to provide a little more context to your question.

Answer (score 2):

Also, if you don't want your compiler complaining and you know the type of the object, you can cast it.

```
[(UILabel *)objById setTag:5];
```

Answer (score 0):

`id` is not exactly a class. It's a generic type which is used in Objective C for arbitrary object. E.g., method taking any object could look like this

```
-(void) doIt(id parameter);
```

So, saying that your object has type `id` adds no information.

But if you're absolutely certain your object responds to `setTag`, you can just do it: `[object setTag:123]`.
Otherwise, just lookup documentation for the object's classs.

Answer (score 0):

`setTag` should be assumed to be a method that belongs to UIView subclasses. If you are certain that the object in question is indeed a UIView subclass, you would call the method as normal: `[someIdInstance setTag:5];`

Based on your question, I'd presume you may not understand the significance of the `id` type.  An object of type `id` may realistically be a pointer to *any* type of object. You have no guarantee that `setTag:` may in fact be defined for that object, which is typically why code that deals with `id` pointers performs steps like this:

```
  id foo = [self getSomePointer];
  if([foo respondsToSelector:@selector(setTag:)]) {
    [foo setTag:4];
  }
```

The code checks to see if the object even *has* the method before attempting to call it.

Answer (score -1):

usually it goes like

```
object-type.tag = value;
```

like

```
button.tag = 50;
```